# PostgreSQL FATAL canceling authentication due to timeout

Tags: postgresql, configuration, remote, connectivity

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4 Database running on my CentOS 7 Server.

This database has only ever been available to users on the LAN,
however recently I needed to make it available to users outside the LAN
which I did using port forwarding for port 5432 on the server using
our Netgear ADSL Router.

My PostgreSQL database has been configured

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf

```
host   dbname   usname   all   md5
```

Everything seems to be working fine, the users can access the database from the internet however there are several times during the day where they cannot connect.

When I check the logs it's always when I see the message

```
FATAL canceling authentication due to timeout
```

Why is this? Do I need to add further configurations to accommodate this?

Comment: Seems more like a network issue than an RDBMS issue.